# Creating a Windows explorer like directory tree

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets, windows-shell

Currently, I am using wxWidgets' wxGenericDirCtrl, which gives me a user interface to the directory tree. It looks like this:

[image: wxGenericDirCtrl]

However, I would prefer it to look like this:

[image: Windows Explorer directory tree]

Talking with the wxWidgets developers, they suggest that one good way to proceed is to modify the wxGenericDirCtrl class to use the native Windows directory control.  I would like to contribute this functionality to wxWidgets myself, but I'm not sure where to start, and could use some suggestions to get me started.

Questions:

1. What's the correct native way to create such a control in C++. Do I use MFC, .NET, or something else?
2. Are there any keywords which can help me find this information?
3. Is there any example code showing how to do this?

Comment: In terms of how it is done, look at the USBView example from Microsoft, it's a good one.

Comment: MFC uses `CMFCShellTreeCtrl`, it is not a native control like `TreeView`. I assume it's not practical to use it in wxwidgets. You can try WinAPI [Shell functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776426(v=vs.85).aspx) instead

Comment: Why not create a `TreeView` control and implement all necessary - fill with file names with `FindFirst`, etc. BTW first example includes files (.txt) and Windows Explorer tree has only folders.

Answer (score 6):

Creating a Window Explorer like directory tree (known as "shell namespace tree control") has become quite easy since Windows Vista. This control can be created through a COM class called [`INameSpaceTreeControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761630(v=vs.85).aspx). Windows 7 added a newer version of this class called [`INameSpaceTreeControl2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378329(v=vs.85).aspx).

The following sample code could be called from the `WM_CREATE` handler of the parent window. It creates a namespace tree control that has its root set to the desktop folder. Other root folders are possible, even multiple roots can be inserted.

```
#include <ShlObj.h>   //Shell COM API
#include <atlbase.h>  //CComPtr

static CComPtr<INameSpaceTreeControl> pTree;
if( SUCCEEDED( pTree.CoCreateInstance( CLSID_NamespaceTreeControl ) ) )
{
    RECT rc{ 0, 0, 444, 333 }; // Client coordinates of the tree control
    if( SUCCEEDED( pTree->Initialize( hWndParent, &rc, 
            NSTCS_HASEXPANDOS | NSTCS_AUTOHSCROLL | NSTCS_FADEINOUTEXPANDOS ) ) )
    {
        CComPtr<IShellItem> pItem;
        if( SUCCEEDED( SHCreateItemInKnownFolder( FOLDERID_Desktop, 0, nullptr, 
                                                  IID_PPV_ARGS( &pItem ) ) ) )
        {
            pTree->AppendRoot( pItem, SHCONTF_FOLDERS, NSTCRS_EXPANDED, nullptr );
        }
    }
}
```

Destroy the namespace tree control by calling the `Release()` method of the COM object when the parent window gets destroyed, typically in the `WM_DESTROY` handler of the parent window:

```
pTree.Release();  // Releases the COM object and sets the pointer to nullptr
```

Don't forget to `CoInitialize(nullptr)` once at startup of your program and `CoUninitialize()` before shutdown.

Comment: This was helpful! In case it helps others: At least in Windows 10, I found that releasing the interface didn't destroy the window. In fact, there was no need to keep the interface pointer at all after creation. Also, MSDN doesn't document a really important thing: Use IUnknown_GetWindow to get the control's HWND which you can use to resize it, destroy it (if you need to and the parent isn't being destroyed), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

wxWidgets does NOT use MFC, .NET or whatever other high-level library on Windows. Just the basic system API (libs kernel32, winspool, comctl32, etc). Same goes for OSX, using the OS provided API. In Linux there's no such "basic API", and thus wxWidgets uses GTK+.

You already have the keywords to search for: *explorer like control*.

`wxGenericDirCtrl` has `GetTreeCtrl()`member. Then, just add images to nodes, for example by `wxTreeCtrl::AssignButtonsImageList()`. See [wx docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_tree_ctrl.html)

Comment: My question is not about modifying the icons in wxGenericDirCtrl, but actually using the native control if it's possible.  Are you saying that this would be impossible in wxWidgets, and that the only way to do it is to create a new control that looks like the Windows one?

Comment: I don't know of a [MS native control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491(v=vs.85).aspx) that looks like you want. I think that MS uses a TreeView with customized expand-buttons and images. This is what `wxGenericDirCtrl`does.