# How to select a folder from a listbox? (C++, WinAPI)

Tags: c++, winapi, listbox

I've seen answers for this all over the place but not for non-MFC C++. I already know how to populate a listbox with the contents of a folder - that's not what I want. I need a listbox to have a small folder picker so I can display the contents of the selected item (the files therein) in a separate list box. Again, I know how to achieve all of this except for having a folder picker inside a listbox.

I've looked at all the listbox functions on MSDN and there was only like four or five functions there and none of them seem to do this.

I don't really have any relevant code to post related to this question, so I hope what I have explained here is good enough.

Here's a picture of what I'm trying to replicate:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: There is no native Win32 control for what you are looking for. You have to make your own from scratch using Win32/Shell APIs to enumerate the folder/file info, and a TreeView or owner-drawn ListBox/ListView to display it. Or  use a 3rd party wrapper that does everything for you.

Comment: It is a plain treeview, not a listbox.  Do consider standard UI for this, SHBrowseForFolder() or IFileOpenDialog with FOS_PICKFOLDERS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Windows explorer like directory tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586051/creating-a-windows-explorer-like-directory-tree)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Since Windows Vista, there is `INameSpaceTreeControl`.

Comment: The picture probably shows a listbox (custom draw), not a treeview because 16-bit Windows did not have a treeview control. You probably don't want to replicate 25 year old designs...

Comment: The dialog box you show is from the Windows 3.1 era, and it looks horribly ancient. Modern Windows uses list views for things like this. Also, you should use the standard dialogs as far as possible, as suggested by Hans Passant.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yeah, my library does both actually. I'm contributing to an open source game engine clone, and the game engine's functions I am cloning has both the much newer and this older look - both of which are now implemented. :)